# Check if duplicate rule is enabled for sObject via Apex or API

Tags: apex, rest-api, duplicate-management

I use Rest API to create a bunch of records users key in.

Sometimes, the subscriber orgs have duplicate rules enabled for the sObjects we use, and since the `DuplicateRuleHeader` is missing from REST API the save simply fails.

Since i do not want to create a custom Apex Rest endpoint just to create sObjects, is it possible given a sObject type to find out if duplicate management is enabled for it?

**Update** I can't use an actual sObject for this, at the decision point all i have is my `sObject.sObjectType`

**Update 2** My users don't have `View Setup and Configuration` permission so they can't query `DuplicateRule` sObject

Comment: Are you talking about this? This is metadata API, which had details about metadata - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_duplicaterule.htm

Comment: @YsrShk No, i am not talking about Metadata API. As a normal user (non admin) they won't have access to it. This is for normal API, to detect somehow whether these rules are even enabled so we can try to avoid the issue.

Comment: @identigral i wish, sadly that requires me to actually submit a `findDuplicates` but my question says `given a sObject type` not 'if i had a sObject'

Answer (score 1):

You can query `DuplicateRule` object via SOQL:

`SELECT Id, DeveloperName,MasterLabel FROM DuplicateRule WHERE sObjectType = 'Contact' AND isActive = true`

will return 1 or more rows if the rule is active for this sObject type.

Comment: I REALLY like this approach. The problem is, without 'View Setup and Configuration' permission, i am getting `sObject type 'DuplicateRule' is not supported.`